# Prevent foreign characters in filenames?

Tags: assets, upload, files

It seems that some of our users are uploading filenames with foreign characters...

[image: uploaded files]

**Is there any way to prevent this?**

I'd like to keep the filenames to all English letters (plus numbers, dash & underscore).

(If relevant, this is for Craft 2.)

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd intelligently map non-roman characters to roman characters. Is there a reason you need to exclude foreign characters?

Comment: Long story... these images get pushed out in a weekly email. Then that email gets forwarded via a GroupMail process (which I am not familiar with). The foreign characters seem to be breaking GroupMail.

Comment: Honestly, even just stripping them out would work. The actual filenames are unimportant, so even replacing each one with a timestamp might be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant you just use `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $stuff)` for this? Seems that will strip away anything that isnt a number or a letter from the english alphabet?

EDIT ---------
Challenge accepted ;)

```
public function modifyAssetFilename($filename){
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", '', $filename);
}
```

Something according to the above strips out all unwanted characters using the hook if you place it in a plugins main class file. The above preg_replace should also keep dashes e.t.c.

Another way you might be able to approach the sanitation of filenames is listening to the `onBeforeSaveAsset` method and then using `craft()->assets->renameFile()` once you have sanitized it. Not sure which one is better. Both should work.

Comment: Based on my own research, looks like you're halfway there. If your answer mentioned how to use this in the context of the `modifyAssetFilename` hook, I would mark it as correct.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I also appreciate the alternative option.